# go to specific component view from router-link

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

Is there a way to got to a specific component from route that it has several components?, I search the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html) but there is nothing about it

here you have my shortened routes in app router:

```
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
    {
        path: "/",
        name: "home",
        component: HomeView,
    }
    {
        path: "/configuracion",
        name: "configuracion",
        components: {
            default: DatosClienteView,
            DatosClienteView,
            GestionUsuarios,
            Notificaciones,
            SelectorClientes,
        },
        meta: {
            sons: [
                {
                    name: "Cliente",
                    componente: "DatosClienteView",
                    icono: "mdi-account",
                    activo: "success",
                },
                {
                    name: "Gestiones",
                    componente: "GestionUsuarios",
                    icono: "mdi-menu",
                    activo: "",
                },
                {
                    name: "Notificaciones",
                    componente: "Notificaciones",
                    icono: "mdi-bell",
                    activo: "",
                },
                {
                    name: "Selector cliente",
                    componente: "SelectorClientes",
                    icono: "mdi-account-group",
                    activo: "",
                },
            ],
        },
    },
];
```

What I'd need is from another route of the app is to display a specific component of the /configuration route. something like:

```
<routerLink :to="{name: 'configuracion', component: 'Notificaciones'}"><p> link</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that can be achieved in other way around by using vue build in special element

```js
<template>
  <component :is="actualComponentToRender">
 </template>
 
 <script setup>
import {DatosClienteView,GestionUsuarios,Notificaciones, SelectorClientes } from 'client'
 
 onMounted(() => {
   actualComponentToRender = router.param.type == 'condition' ? DatosClienteView
 })
}
</script>
 </script>
```

[Refer to this link for more informatin](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component)

Answer (score 1):

With Options API, you can navigate to any destination like this

```js
this.$route.push({name: 'configuracion'})
```

With Composition API (Vuejs 3), we don't have access to **this** inside of `setup`, instead we use `useRouter` and user `userRoute` functions

```js
<script>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter();

    function yourMethod(query) {
      router.push({
        name: 'configuracion',
      })    
    }

    return {
      yourMethod,
    };
  },
}
</script>
```